# Email aren't been sent in Aldryn forms, even though email backend is configured

Tags: forms, django-cms

I'm using Aldryn forms to submit contact page. In aldryn forms when the contact form is submitted it can be seen in the admin panel.
Including this, I need to receive email notifications.
As I've already worked on a few email notification projects in Django.

I've provided the relevant code for the email-backend config.

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'abc@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'xxx'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
```

When the contact form is submitted I need to receive an email in abc@gmail.com
please let me know if anything I'm missing out or wrongly configured.

Comment: What platform is your project running on?

Comment: My Operating system is Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the issue after filling "Recipients" section in "Email notifications" inside settings of "Form" plugin (aldryn-forms plugin of Djangocms in my case).   Settings are correct - work for me.